# Parent has background color, but child is transparent

Tags: css

I was wondering if it was possible to have a parent div have a particular background color, and the child div, be transparent using only CSS.

Let me show you a diagram, which displays what I want: 
[image]

I can't do it with two sibling Divs, because the divs have rounded corners.
I could do this, using images for the corners, and sibling divs, but I'll like to know if there is a elegant and simple way of doing what I want, with only CSS.

Comment: In fact, the child is **transparent**, but under it, is blue.

Comment: @user2417834: Exactly, I want to make it so that whatever is under the parent div, is visible through the child Div element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with siblings and allow rounded corners only for the corners you want. [This page](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) has good information about how to do it. It basically consists on using: `border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;`.

So,

```
<div id = "container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container div:first-child
  {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  }

#container div:last-child
  {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  /* Same color as the sibling div and a distance of the radius + the separation */
  box-shadow: -12px 0 blue;
  }
```

<strike>I think that should work.</strike> It works. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QMsp/) with some more aesthetic modifications (for resembling more to your image).

EDIT: the right one needed a radius with the border in the original color, so I put together a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QMsp/1/) and edited the code above.

Comment: I was just going for the fiddle (;

Comment: My diagram maybe was not clear. The child div has 4 rounded corners. even if the first sibling which has a background, has no rounded corners, there is a small gap near the rounded corners which has no background.

Comment: Oh I see, you want the gap to be blue then... wow, hold on, I need to find something I saw some time ago

Comment: It turns out it wasn't the same (it was [this](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/) ). Although I have thought of a small hack. I'll try it and see how it goes. Where will the content be? Will it be JUST in the border?

Comment: Yeah! I hacked it. See it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QMsp/1/). Basically, I added a small `box-shadow` in blue to the left of the transparent div, and it doesn't show up behind the transparent div, only on the sides. Hope you like it (:

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos: Awesome! Can you please update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks! I'd check this in IE though, some older versions might not be too compatible.